# SEO for html single-page site via quasi-html content

Tags: javascript, html, seo, single-page-application

Suppose, I have a javaScript-heavy single page web application. My Javascript render dom directly from model / datasource (Json).

I came up with an approach to generate simple html from datasource (on backend). This html is required only for search engines to index. After page is loaded, JavaScript will replace this quasi-html  with the proper UI. Quasi-html can be removed from layout with display:none to avoid performance penalty on the browser.

Will it work? 
Also I am concerned about legitimacy of the approach.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work giving the search engines content to craw even if they don't read javascript. Now bots evolve and they read quite a bit of javascript nowadays, I've created a page that only has 2 sentences onBeforeLoad and uses Ajax to get the rest of the content and I see Google indexing a lot of the keywords delivered by Ajax. A problem would be misleading the search bot, like putting in content irrelevant to your other page content - something the bot might pick up at some point and penalize you for it. "I am concerned about legitimacy of the approach" - I wouldn't be, keep code valid and ride on